# ADFS Multiple Group

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I am implemented integration using ADFS. I need to send all the groups the user belongs to.

I cannot find any claims which does this. Please some one suggest me the approach for this. Do we need to write custom rules for this ?

Thanks,
Sanjay Vithani

Answer (score 1):

Use "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims".

And then use one of the "Token-Groups" rules e.g. "Token Groups - Unqualified Names". Map this to Role.